# error accessing web htaccess AH01797: client denied by server configuration

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm getting error when i open my website externaly.
I'm getting this error:
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

If i delete my .htaccess, it is not giving me error, but is showing me the path of /htdocs and i have configured a SubFolder.

If i open localhost:80 it redirects correctly to the subfolder htdocs/folder-name
The problem is when i open it via [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) externaly.

This is my .htaccess.
Path: C:\Apache24\htdocs.htaccess
Content:

```
#DON'T SHOW DIRECTORY LISTINGS
 Options -Indexes

#FOLLOW SYMBOLIC LINKS
 Options +FollowSymLinks

#SET DEFAULT HANDLER
 DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

 RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^DOMAIN.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.DOMAIN.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !FOLDER/
RewriteRule (.*) /FOLDER/$1 [L]


#ERROR 404 PAGE
 ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

APACHE LOG:

```
client denied by server configuration: C:/Apache24/htdocs/WEBSITE-XX/
[AH01797: client denied by server configuration: C:/Apache24/error/HTTP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
 AH01797: client denied by server configuration: C:/Apache24/htdocs/WEBSITE-XX/favicon.ico, referer: https://www.example.com/
 AH01797: client denied by server configuration: C:/Apache24/error/HTTP_FORBIDDEN.html.var, referer: https://www.example.com/
```

** rewrite module is active and the path is correct **

httpd.conf code of VirtualHost

***EDIT***

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot C:\Apache24\htdocs\example
    ErrorLog C:\Apache24\logs\error.log
    CustomLog C:\Apache24\logs\access.log combined

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot C:\Apache24\htdocs\example
    ErrorLog C:\Apache24\logs\error.log
    CustomLog C:\Apache24\logs\access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile C:\Apache24\conf\certificate.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile C:\Apache24\conf\private.key

</VirtualHost>
```

**** EDIT WITH NEW HTTPD.CONF ****

`````
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot C:\Apache24\htdocs\example
    ErrorLog C:\Apache24\logs\error.log
    CustomLog C:\Apache24\logs\access.log combined
<Directory C:\Apache24\htdocs\example>
    # Requried for mod_rewrite (and disable Indexes / MultiViews)
    Options FollowSymLinks

    # Allow access
    Require all granted

    # Enabled .htaccess overrides
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
    Redirect 301 / https://example.com/
    # RewriteEngine on
    # RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com [OR]
    # RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com
    # RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot C:\Apache24\htdocs\example
    ErrorLog C:\Apache24\logs\error.log
    CustomLog C:\Apache24\logs\access.log combined
    
<Directory C:\Apache24\htdocs\example>
    # Requried for mod_rewrite (and disable Indexes / MultiViews)
    Options FollowSymLinks

    # Allow access
    Require all granted

    # Enabled .htaccess overrides
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile C:\Apache24\conf\certificate.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile C:\Apache24\conf\private.key

</VirtualHost>
````
`````

Comment: "client denied by **server configuration**" - So, what's the server config? How have you configured the VirtualHost? Have you allowed access? Was this previously a working site and then stopped after some update? Or are you trying to set this up the first time? This does not seem to be anything to do with your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: @MrWhite  i added virtualhost config in httpd.conf, sry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>     :
>     DocumentRoot C:\Apache24\htdocs\example
>     :
>
> <VirtualHost *:443>
>     :
>     DocumentRoot C:\Apache24\htdocs\Mymxtools
> ```

Confusingly, you have defined a different `DocumentRoot` for the two VirtualHosts. (Maybe this is an error in your exemplification?) Although you are redirecting everything to HTTPS, so this doesn't really matter as it happens.

However, you have not "allowed" access to this part of the filesystem or enabled `.htaccess` overrides.

You would need something like the following in the `<VirtualHost *:443>` container to grant access and enable `.htaccess` overrides.

```
<Directory C:\Apache24\htdocs\Mymxtools>
    # Requried for mod_rewrite (and disable Indexes / MultiViews)
    Options FollowSymLinks

    # Allow access
    Require all granted

    # Enabled .htaccess overrides
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com [OR]
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com
> RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
> ```

To redirect everything from HTTP to HTTPS in the `<VirtualHost *:80>` container, you don't need this "complex" mod_rewrite rule. A much simpler mod_alias `Redirect` is sufficient (and preferred).

For example, use the following instead:

```
Redirect 301 / https://example.com/
```

You should canonicalise the hostname at this stage. Your previous mod_rewrite rule would preserve the hostname, ie. www or non-www.

Comment: still giving me the same error in apache logs and searching for the website, could be an error for the windows folder pathing? I updated my code cuz i dont know where to put de <Directory></Directory>
I dont know which is correct 1 or 2

1.- C:\Apache\xxx
2.-C:/Apache/xxx

Comment: @user18939999 Presumably you've restarted Apache? Have you included these VirtualHosts directly in the server config? Are they being applied? "i dont know where to put de `<Directory></Directory>`" - as I stated: "in the `<VirtualHost *:443>` container". You don't need these in the vHost:80 container since you are redirecting everything to HTTPS. On Windows, you can use either backslash or forward-slash.

Comment: yes, i restarted it and still giving me error, could i try to "  Require all granted" in all folders? If letting all folders permission it's impossible to get access denied.

Comment: @user18939999 The `<Directory>` directive applies to the stated directory and all subdirectories. Are you creating this site _within_ another site? Ordinarily, `/htdocs` is the document root. Try creating this site in a different area of the file system, in case a parent config is conflicting.

Comment: If i remove .htaccess it is working fine. It shows me the webpage that is in the folder htdocs/Example automatically and i dont have to put example.com/example to go there.